# Compare Two Logistic Regression Models

Tags: logistic, likelihood

I have worked out two models to fit the data (blue) - the first (in green) is the baseline model with the intercept only. The second (red) is the model with the intercept and 2 parameters.

Obviously, the second describes the data much better. However, I have got insignificant Likelihood Ratio test. As far as I can see, LH functions are indeed not very different for the given data points.

What's going on here?

[image: two models]

Comment: I find that very hard to believe. Can you post data and or output of the analysis?

Answer (score 2):

The proportions of successes (deaths, marriages, ...) is very small. So even in large datasets, these test won't be very powerfull. This may be the explanation for your insignificant results.